# VBA macro to combine two sheets on unique id

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in Excel workbook. 
**The first sheet has**

1)  Customer ID – unique values for each customer.

2)  Question ID – unique id for each question

3)  Questions

```
            Customer ID     Question ID question        

            1               34              name        
            1               45              company 
            2               34              name        
            2               45              company     
            3               34              name        
            3               45              company     
            4               34              name        
            4               45              company     
            5               34              name        
            5               45              company
```

**The second sheet has three columns**

1)  Customer ID – unique values for each customer.

2)  Question ID – unqiue id for each question

3)  Questions

```
            Customer ID     Question ID   Answer

            1                   34          Amy
            1                   45          GEICO
            2                   34          Steph
            3                   34          Anna
            3                   45          GEICO
            4                   34          Adam
            5                   34          Mark
            5                   45          AAA
```

In this sheet, not every customer id and Question ID in sheet one will have answers in the sheet 2

**Sheet 3  Expected Output**

I wanted to do a vba macro to combine both sheet1 and sheet2 and have all the columns. For any customer id, if there is no answer for  a question, that field should be left blank.

**Expected Output in Sheet3**

```
            Customer ID     Question ID    question     Answer

            1               34              name        Amy
            1               45              company     GEICO
            2               34              name        Steph
            2               45              company     
            3               34              name        Anna
            3               45              company     GEICO
            4               34              name        Adam
            4               45              company     
            5               34              name        Mark
            5               45              company     AAA
```

Comment: You should check `VLOOKUP` function in Excel.

Comment: @buddy - Is there a reason you need to do this in VBA, rather than using the built-in tools? There are several ways this can be done without writing code.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: You may also consider using `Power Query` to get the desired output. If you are using `Excel 2010 or later`, you may download this `free Add-In` from `MS site`. It is built in `Excel-2016` and `Office-365`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways this can be done without writing code.

Below is one method off the top of my head. Others include the built-in query editor ([Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/article/get-transform-in-excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de)), or [PivotTables](https://support.office.com/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576?ocmsassetID=HA102840046&CorrelationId=5d9bba28-676d-40bb-ab4a-9963b9786c69) and others ways to [consolidate data in multiple worksheets](http://consolidate%20data%20in%20multiple%20worksheets/).

---

On `Sheet2`, first set up a "helper column" since there are multiple columns you want to match.  In this example the formula is: `=C2&D2` starting in Cell `B2`.

[image: img]

...then, in `Sheet1` (cell `E2` in the example), use a formula like:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2&C2,Sheet2!$B$1:$E$9,4,FALSE),"")
```

[image: img]

Both formulas get copied or "dragged" down as far as necessary and obviously the formula adjusted to refer to the correct cells.

No third worksheet is necessary but if you want you can start by copying `Sheet1` to `Sheet3`.

---

### More Information:

- Microsoft Support : [**`VLOOKUP` Function**](https://support.office.com/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)
- Microsoft Support : [**Lookup & Reference Functions**](https://support.office.com/article/lookup-and-reference-functions-reference-8aa21a3a-b56a-4055-8257-3ec89df2b23e)
- Microsoft Support : [**`IFERROR` Function**](https://support.office.com/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)